# How to display the whole table of my job including their categories that I had to create from mySQL Workbench to php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, workbench

This is my php code for displaying the table from mySQL workbench:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(' SELECT jobs.*, categories.category_name
        FROM jobs
        LEFT JOIN vacancies.categories ON categories.category_id = jobs.category_id
        WHERE jobs.category_id =:category_id');

$choice = 0;// just a temp for test

$criteria = [
    'category_id' => $choice,
];

$stmt -> execute($criteria);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<br>' . $row['id']. ' ' . $row['title']. ' ' . $row['salary']. ' ' . $row['location']. ' ' . $row['description']. '<br> category is:'.$row['category_name'].'</br>';
}
```

Now if I run this and check my webpage it only shows the jobs that hve the `category_id` of the `$choice` I put but I want to display all of the job table. 
I have a category table with 6 categories (0 is the start) and in my other table that is called jobs. I have 7 jobs with their details.

I hope someone understand what I am trying to say and can help me out. Ask me anything if I don't give out enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a prepared query to norrow the results to a defined criteria. If you want to display all the jobs you should simply remove the `WHERE` tag and use a simple query

```
$stmt = $pdo->query(' SELECT jobs.*, categories.category_name
    FROM jobs
    LEFT JOIN vacancies.categories ON categories.category_id = jobs.category_id');

echo '<table>';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['id']. '</td><td>' . $row['title']. '</td><td>' . $row['salary']. '</td><td>' . $row['location']. '</td><td>' . $row['description'].'</td><td> category is:'.$row['category_name'].'</td></tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Hey, i have tried and its showing me Error that is on the line 12 which is basically this line 

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo '<br>' . $row['id']. ' ' . $row['title']. ' ' . $row['salary']. ' ' . $row['location']. ' ' . $row['description']. '<br> category is:'.$row['category_name'].'</br>';

Comment: What does the stack trace say ?

Comment: I've tried again and its still shows me an Error.
The Error says this "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in E:\3 Web Programming\wamp\www\public_html\vacancies.php on line 12" which is still the 'while' line 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo '<br>' . $row['id']. ' ' . $row['title']. ' ' . $row['salary']. ' ' . $row['location']. ' ' . $row['description'].'</br>';

Comment: I think I messed up in the joint par this should work now

Comment: Hey GREAT it worked !! 
Do you also know how i can create this database that i display on my page with php into a html table to neat it more up?

Comment: Yes you can use html tags directly within `echo` then add some styles in your stylesheet to display it. `table, tr, td {border: 1px solid black;}`

Comment: where would i have to put the name of one column in the script for the table? As im trying to show which row is ID Title Salary Location and also putting the Category is as well at the top. If you get what I mean

Comment: Also i have tried couple of times now but the style table, tr, td {border: 1px solid black;} is not working for the table and doesnt put them in a table 
it looks different and better then before but not in a table.

Comment: Just after the `echo <table>;` you can use put a `echo '<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>...</td> (...) <td>Last Column</td></tr>';` as for the stylesheet try adding `table {border-collapse:collapse;}`